# WordPress/PHP and Links

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a line of code that should be spitting out the phrase "Testing 1"

Instead it's spitting out the letter "h".
The exact line of code is in reference to the link tag with in the UL/LI.

My goal is to have the link tag link to individual blogs however using the blog name which is currently referred to as more_blogs_title I am not sure why it is pulling an "h" in I can't find any issues within that line of code at the moment so looking for some help.

Thanks :)

```
<section>
<?php if ( have_rows( 'blog_layout' ) ): ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'blog_layout' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php if ( get_row_layout() == 'blog_structure' ) : ?>
            <?php $hero_image = get_sub_field( 'hero_image' ); ?>
            <?php if ( $hero_image ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $hero_image['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $hero_image['alt'] ); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1><?php the_sub_field( 'blog_title' ); ?></h1>
            <?php if ( have_rows( 'blog_body_copy' ) ) : ?>
                <?php while ( have_rows( 'blog_body_copy' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <p><?php the_sub_field( 'blog_body_copy_area' ); ?><p>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php // No rows found ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="wrapper">

            <h2><?php the_sub_field( 'more_blogs_header' ); ?></h2>
            <?php if ( have_rows( 'more_blogs_links' ) ) : ?>
                <?php while ( have_rows( 'more_blogs_links' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <?php $link_to_blogs = get_sub_field( 'link_to_blogs' ); ?>
                    <?php if ( $link_to_blogs ) : ?>
        
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_to_blogs); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_to_blogs ['more_blogs_title']); ?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php // No rows found ?> 
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php // No layouts found ?>
<?php endif; ?>

        
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: "I have a line of code..." - which line is that? I see about 40 lines of code here, and it's not clear which of them you think is the problem, or why the others are relevant to the question. It would be useful to reduce the code to a [mre] and more clearly explain where the problem is.

Comment: i mentioned in my post it was the line with the link in it.

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_to_blogs); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_to_blogs ['more_blogs_title']); ?></a>

Comment: what is the value of `$link_to_blogs` ?

Comment: It's the actual link itself.

Comment: The link it's self is working what's not working is the 'more_blogs_title' I am getting a return of an h instead of "Testing 1"...

Comment: @ITgoldman I added two pictures for you to see as an answer but it's not resolved yet.

Comment: if it's the link itself, then `$link_to_blogs ['more_blogs_title']` is wrong. try `get_sub_field('more_blogs_title')`

Comment: @ITgoldman The link itself is right, but if you like at the two images I provided in the answers it isn't showing "testing 1" it's showing "h"...

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I think `$link_to_blogs ['more_blogs_title']` is wrong. try

```php
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_to_blogs); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_sub_field('more_blogs_title')); ?></a></li>
```

instead of that line.

Comment: That wasn't the right solution sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So I used a plugin called Classic Widgets, and changed some code to get this working.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_to_blogs['url'] ); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_to_blogs['target'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_to_blogs['title'] ); ?></a>
```